# How to exit from a try/except inside of an if/else statement in Python

Tags: python, django

So I have this:

```
if condition:
    ...
elif condition2:
    ...
elif condition3:
    try:
        existing_bid = # get some object from django models 
    except SomeError: # if this object does not exist
        # here I need to escape from if/else to main scope
    if ... # some comparison with an existing_bid:
        #return error
    ... # try to manipulate existing_bid object and save it
# here I need to escape
...
...
```

What is the best practice to escape from try/except that is inside of an if/else to main scope?
Thanks


**edit:**

provided some context

Comment: If there is no `elif` after the try-except, you can just use `pass`.

Comment: Alternatively, put the whole structure in a short function, and use `return` in the `except` part.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If one condition (in this case `condition3`) is `True`, then it executes the code under that condition and skips any other `elif` statements that follow, therefore, you don't need to escape if/else. If you have the if/else conditions in a loop and need to escape that, you can use `break`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape after the try/except and back to the main scope. It will be easy to handle if you put the try/except statement at the bottom of your `elif` condition 3. Once it finishes the `try/except` statement, the program will also finish the `elif` statement and escape to the main scope.

Otherwise, you have to put a `break` in your `try/except` code.

Comment: but it is not a loop to break out from? `SyntaxError: break outside loop`

Comment: Just replace `break` with `pass`.

Comment: Yes, just use `pass` at the end of your `except` statement.